# mongo3.0 restore fails with error Failed: restore error: insertion error: EOF

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore a database with 100 collections (800GB) using mongorestore which was taken as a backup from mongo 2.4.4. I used the following command:

```
mongorestore -u <username> -p <password> -d bp_prod079 
             /data/backup/2015-11-28/bp_prod079 --batchSize=100
```

I'm using batchSize =1000, 500, 100 to try to make it work. I'm getting an insertion error after 10-15 collections. It almost runs for almost an hour and half perfectly when I get this error.

> Failed: restore error: bp_prod079.ANEpisodeBreakdown: error restoring
>   from /data/backup/2015-11-28/bp_prod079/ANEpisodeBreakdown.bson:
>   insertion error: EOF

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l /data/backup/2015-11-28/bp_prod079/ANEpisodeBreakdown.bson`?  Is it an empty file by any chance?

Comment: ls -l /data/backup/2015-11-28/bp_prod079/ANEpisodeBreakdown.bson               
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1413518186 Nov 28 07:21 /data/backup/2015-11-28/bp_prod079/ANEpisodeBreakdown.bson

Comment: It is not an empty file. I opened a ticket with MongoDB-JIRA as well. They say there is a bug in 3.0.7. They asked me to use  --batchSize=1 as last resort. If that doesn't work then I have to wait for 3.0.8.

Comment: You can use 3.0.6 mongorestore on that backup - I assume you're refering to TOOLS-939 in jira?

Comment: Yes. It is TOOLS-939.

Answer (score 14):

For me with a minor batchSize works. First I had `--batchSize=50` and changed it to 10 `--batchSize=10` and perfect.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me! Where did you find that?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry hehe Googling and making a lot of tests until it worked.

Comment: Perfect, That worked for me. I tried 1000, 100 but only 10 work.

Answer (score 2):

On MongoDB servers using the WiredTiger storage engine (default on MongoDB v3.2.x), this error can also be thrown when running out of memory, causing both `mongorestore` and `mongod` to crash, as MongoDB developer @mpobrien explains [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/issues/60#issuecomment-197938682).

The solution is to add more RAM to the server, or tune the `storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB` setting as described here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/Ms2MXCajreg/OsW6ixcSCgAJ

Comment: This worked for me. I set cacheSizeGB to 1 in my 2GB server.